# Odoo add and existing field to a report

Tags: python, report, crm, odoo

In Odoo there is a report `OpportunityReport` in `addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report.py`. I know that it takes fields from `crm.lead`. Except one field I need: `name` which is also in `crm.lead`.

I would modify the existing `OpportunityReport` as following:

```
Index: odoo/addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report.py
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- odoo/addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report.py    (date 1523367742000)
+++ odoo/addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report.py    (date 1523367742000)
@@ -13,6 +13,7 @@
     _description = "CRM Opportunity Analysis"
     _rec_name = 'date_deadline'

+    name = fields.Char('Name', readonly=True)
     date_deadline = fields.Date('Expected Closing', readonly=True)
     create_date = fields.Datetime('Creation Date', readonly=True)
     opening_date = fields.Datetime('Assignation Date', readonly=True)
@@ -54,6 +55,7 @@
             CREATE VIEW crm_opportunity_report AS (
                 SELECT
                     c.id,
+                    c.name,
                     c.date_deadline,

                     c.date_open as opening_date,
```

But AFAIK I should not break existing customizations in db regarding this report. How can I update that report? Do I need to create a module?

How can I add a field `name` to this report? I would: first create a custom report (with a new module) that inherits this report and then use that new report, but being novice in Python and Odoo don't know how to do that.

Where do I start? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inherit the view table 'crm.opportunity.report'

Please create a new module and add crm in depends.

Then add this code in youre .py file

```
from odoo import fields, models, tools

from ..models import crm_stage

class OpportunityReport(models.Model):
    """ CRM Opportunity Analysis """

    _inherit = "crm.opportunity.report"


    name = fields.Char('Name', readonly=True)


def init(self):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'crm_opportunity_report')
        self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE VIEW crm_opportunity_report AS (
                SELECT
                    c.id,
                    c.date_deadline,
                    c.name as name,

                    c.date_open as opening_date,
                    c.date_closed as date_closed,
                    c.date_last_stage_update as date_last_stage_update,

                    c.user_id,
                    c.probability,
                    c.stage_id,
                    stage.name as stage_name,
                    c.type,
                    c.company_id,
                    c.priority,
                    c.team_id,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM mail_message m
                     WHERE m.model = 'crm.lead' and m.res_id = c.id) as nbr_activities,
                    c.active,
                    c.campaign_id,
                    c.source_id,
                    c.medium_id,
                    c.partner_id,
                    c.city,
                    c.country_id,
                    c.planned_revenue as total_revenue,
                    c.planned_revenue*(c.probability/100) as expected_revenue,
                    c.create_date as create_date,
                    extract('epoch' from (c.date_closed-c.create_date))/(3600*24) as  delay_close,
                    abs(extract('epoch' from (c.date_deadline - c.date_closed))/(3600*24)) as  delay_expected,
                    extract('epoch' from (c.date_open-c.create_date))/(3600*24) as  delay_open,
                    c.lost_reason,
                    c.date_conversion as date_conversion
                FROM
                    "crm_lead" c
                LEFT JOIN "crm_stage" stage
                ON stage.id = c.stage_id
                GROUP BY c.id, stage.name
            )""")
```

Please notify if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank You:). Your solution was very helpful. I created a custom module with this code and it worked.

Comment: Welcome. Please mark as answer if it was helpful !.

Comment: Here you go :)!